# Excel sumifs with multiple/optional criteria

Tags: excel, sumifs

I have a `sumifs` set up like below and it links to search data by year, period and week.

I am looking to make it so the refined criteria can be ignored at times if just searching for the year or just the period.

Right now the formula will only put out the most refined portion such as the data for a week within a period of a year. I am looking to have a similar formula that puts out data for just the year if the period and week are not needed or all three criteria when needed.

> =SUMIFS(Data!$H$59:Data!$H$59:$H$65536,Data!$D$59:$D$65536,Search!$C12,Data!$C$59:$C$65536,Search!D$4,Data!$A$59:$A$65536,Search!D$5,Data!$E$59:$E$65536,D$6,Data!$F$59:$F$65536,D7,Data!$G$59:$G$65536,Search!D$8)

Comment: Can you give an example, please?

Comment: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/11/12/excel-sumifs-sumif-multiple-criteria/

Comment: The first picture of the spreadsheet on this page. My question pertaining to this would be how to search for just apples overall, regardless of the name.